# How can I determine what parameters to use for AudioFormat?

Tags: java, audio

I have a WAV file here: http://uppit.com/slpmuzpywxhs/202.wav

and I need to construct a Java [AudioFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html) object based on properties of that sound file using the following the parameters:

float sampleRate, int sampleSizeInBits, int channels, boolean signed, boolean bigEndian.

So my question is: How can I analyze that WAV file in order to determine those values?

EDIT: Solution found thanks to jaket!

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: If you tried post your code

Comment: I am able to play the sound file using the following constructor, however the sound is distorted because the parameters are not correct. I am trying to determine the correct parameters to use.

   AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 2, true, true);

Comment: you can try by this parameter :audioFormat = new AudioFormat(8000, 8, 1, true, false)

Comment: Thanks but it is still distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the wave header to determine that the format is:

- 22050 sample rate
- 8 bits per sample
- endianess - irrelevant for 8-bits but may as well say little endian.
- 1 channel

I found this info by downloading the file, right clicking and selecting "Get Info" on the mac. There are lots of other ways to find this out.

If I were writing code for this though I probably wouldn't want to hard code the values though. Google found me this:

```
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream("202.wav");
AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
```